# When are extensions $k(x)/k(s)$ for points in the fiber of a closed point algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $S$ be a local scheme with closed point $s$. Let $x$ be a point in the fiber of $s$ along an étale morphism $X\to S$. Under what conditions is the extension of residue fields $k(x)/k(s)$ algebraic?

[Lemma 28.19.3](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TF) of the stacks project says that in the locally finite type case, $k(x)/k(s)$ is finite iff $x$ is closed in the fiber of $s$. This does not assume $s$ is a closed point.

Comment: The fiber $X_s$ is locally finite type over the field $k(s)$. The residue fields don't change when passing from $X$ to $X_s$, so this is really all just the Nullstellensatz I think.

Comment: @Hoot could you elaborate on the Nullstellensatz part? Also, if $S$ is taken to be the spectrum of a separably closed field, does $k(x)=k(s)$ always hold?

Comment: I guess it depends whether you're in the situation of your first paragraph or the second. I was mostly referring to the second — I think it's better to understand that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are asking about residue fields in the fibre over the closed point $s$, you can just replace $X \to S$ by its base-change $X_s \to \operatorname{Spec} k(s)$ via the canonical closed immersion Spec $k(s) \to S$, and so your question becomes: if $k$ is a field and $X \to $ Spec $k$ is etale, for which points $x \in X$ is the residue field  extension $k(x)/k$ algebraic?  The answer is: for all of them, as Hoot's comment indicates.  (They are also all separable.  Indeed, a morphism $X \to $ Spec $k$ is etale precisely if the domain is a disjoint union of $k$-schemes of the form Spec $l$, where $l$ is a finite separable extension of $k$.)

Comment: Could you explain hoot's comment and why the Nullstellensatz justifies it?

Comment: In particular, if $S$ is the spectrum of a separably closed field, does $k(x)=k(s)$ always hold?

Comment: We have $X \to $ Spec $k$ etale, thus locally f.t., thus if $x \in X$, there is a finite type affine open n.h. Spec $A$ of $x$ in $X$, which is then etale over $k$, and so the problem is to compute the structure of a finite type etale $k$-algebra.   This is an exercise, or also in any standard text, or the Stacks Project.  (As is the statement I made about the general structure of etale schemes over fields.)

Comment: Also, since (as I wrote) $k(x)/k(s)$ is finite separable, it is certainly the trivial extension if $k(s)$ is separably closed.